# Download html without Python unicode errors

Tags: python, html, xml, unicode, character-encoding

I am trying to download page_source to a file. However, every time I get a:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 (or something else) in 
position 8304: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried using `value.encode('utf-8')`, but it seems every time it throws the same exception (in addition to manually trying to replace every non-ascii character). Is there a way to 'pre-process' the html to put it into a 'write-able' format?

Comment: What is the actual encoding of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are third party libraries such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [lxml](http://lxml.de/) that can deal with encoding issues automatically. But here's a crude example using just `urlllib2`:

First download some webpage containing non-ascii characters:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/unicode-sample.html')
>>> data = response.read()
```

Now have a look for the "charset" at the top of the page:

```
>>> data[:200]
'<html>\n<head>\n<title>Unicode 2.0 test page</title>\n<meta
content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-type"/>\n
</head>\n<body>\n<p>This page contains characters from each of the
Unicode\ncharact'
```

If there was no obvious charset, "UTF-8" is usually a good guess, anyway.

Finally, convert the webpage to unicode text:

```
>>> text = data.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue. When downloading a page with a basic python script I had as a result an html page with xce\xbf\xb9 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, however http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ has a function .prettify() that returns well formatted HTML. You could try using that for "preprocessing".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you're trying to go `str` -> `utf-8`, when you need to go `str` -> `unicode` -> `utf-8`.  In other words, try `unicode(s, 'utf-8').encode('utf-8')`.

See http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/ for more info.